# how to make command to stop reminder, discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have made this-

```
from asyncio import sleep as s

@client.command()
async def reminder(ctx, time: int, *, msg):
    while True:
        await s(time)
        await ctx.send(f'{msg}, {ctx.author.mention}')
```

It's working good.
But can you help me to make command to stop reminder too? *Because if once it starts it never stops.* :(

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a loop?

Comment: You can't really stop the reminder with the current logic of your code, it's not even near the solution, you should take a look at asyncio tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You just had to put `return` after the last line. Here is how I did it, I improved the code a bit as well.

```
@bot.command()
async def reminder(ctx, time: int, *, msg):
  await ctx.send(f'Okay, {ctx.author.mention} I will remind you in {time} seconds to complete {msg}')
  await asyncio.sleep(time)
  await ctx.send(f'{msg}, {ctx.author.mention}')
  return
```

Comment: If you do it like this you don't need while loop at all

Comment: And then you also don't need return

Comment: Thanks!
but I don't want to stop command until user uses a command like `!reminder stop` to stop that reminder.

Comment: You mean you want to cancel the reminder?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to stop the reminder via a `!reminder stop` command, I suggest using a global list of users that currently have a reminder running. This won't work with multiply reminders per user.
First define your list for reminders:

```py
reminderList = []
```

Then in the command, if the user starts the reminder, add them to the reminder list and remove them if they run `!reminder stop`:

```py
@client.command()
async def reminder(ctx, time, *, msg):
    try: #detect if !reminder stop was used
        time = int(time)
    except ValueError:
        if time.lower() == "stop":
            try:
                reminderList.remove(ctx.author.id) #remove them from the list
            except ValueError:
                ctx.send("You don't have a reminder at the moment")
            return
    #add the user to the reminder list:
    reminderList.append(crx.author.id)
    #check if the user is still in the reminder list:
    while ctx.author.id in reminderList:
        await s(time)
        await ctx.send(f'{msg}, {ctx.author.mention}')
```

Answer (score -1):

don't use while true as it will cause issue and it's useless here if u won't use that then too it will work and there is nothing to stop the sleep command other than restarting the bot